# Issues Connecting to University WPA2 Enterprise Network

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, 17.04, wpa2

I am running Ubuntu 17.04 with the Gnome desktop and gnome network manager. I can connect just fine to my WPA2 network at home, as well as any other network that uses WEP, WPA, or WPA2. I can't connect to WPA2 Enterprise networks however.

I know for a fact when I connect on a Windows computer, Android phone, or IOS phone, after supplying my correct credentials it will ask if I would like to accept the networks certificate. If you look at the request information on an iPhone, it will explain how the certificate is not trusted, which leads me to believe that the chain of trust is broken? I have tried getting the CA for the certificate the network issues, but I can't be certain I did get the right one. When looking at the certificate it issues on another machine you can see that the issuer claimed is DigiCert which should by default be in the trusted CA's of the system.

Several other people on campus that use Arch Linux have no issues connecting with netctl (their network manager) using the following config details:

```
Description='NAME OF CONNECTION'
Interface=wlp3s0
Connection=wireless
Security=wpa-configsection
IP=dhcp
IP6=stateless
WPAConfigSection=(
 'ssid="Student"'
 'key_mgmt=WPA-EAP'
 'eap=PEAP'
 'identity="insert your email here"'
 'password="insert your password here"'
 'phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"'
)
```

When I setup my connection info I use the same configuration option, with proper credentials. After a few minutes of waiting it kicks back saying the username and password were incorrect (I know they're not, I select the "don't hide password while typing" option to make sure) and it can't connect.

I have rooted through the internet and have seen many proposed fixes, all of which I was unable to get working. No other students on campus using Ubuntu (or any other "cousin" distro can get this working). It seems only Arch users can get this working...

Comment: You could try disabling Gnome Network Manager `sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service` then `sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager.service`, and just try to use only WPA Supplicant. This is what I use on my university network, and I do not have a certificate. Here is my post; perhaps you can compare what you have with what I have and it could help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343032/manual-configuration-or-wpa-supplicant-for-wifi-on-a-university-network

Comment: I will have to try this when I return to school. There has been a suggestion to downgrade WPA Supplicant to 2.3 because above v2.3 WPA Supplicant immediately denies weak certificates (so I've hear). I'll give both a shot. Although, if I leave the gnome network manager out of this and just use wpa_supplicant, will I be able to tie that into nm-applet?

Comment: I don't know of any applet for it. I just do any network management with command line for example `wavemon` to see signal strength. I have an alias assigned for `sudo iw dev wlan0 scan | grep SSID` to view nearby wifi networks. It works for me, but I am usually on only one of three networks, home, work, or wifi hotspot.

Comment: Yeah I generally will only ever be on Home or School. I might have to use your method. I also will try installing wpa_supplicant v2.6 because that might fix the issue (I figured out 17.4 ships with v2.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer guys. It turns out that wpasupplicant (the package in charge of handling WPA encryption) has an issue in v2.4 (the current Ubuntu package version) with handling WPA2 Enterprise networks. Simply downgrading the package to v2.3 or upgrading the package version to v2.5 (which I did, and I got the deb package from the Kali repo) will solve the issue.